# Disable profile specific property when other profile is active

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am looking for a way to disable some property (use it default value) when 2 profiles are used in conjunction.

My setup includes 3 profiles: dev, prod & debug. The application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
.
.
.
---
spring:
  profiles: dev
.
.
.
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
---
spring:
  profiles: prod
server:
  address: localhost
.
.
.
---
spring:
  profiles: debug

.
.
.
```

When the application runs with dev profile the server binds both on localhost and global IP address. In prod profile the server address is bound to localhost only. I want to enable dev profile behavior when prod and debug profile are active in conjunction. Is it possible out of the box?

Comment: Spring profiles are declared as spring: profiles: active :  dev like you have done in the beginning. But what is this spring: profiles: dev.. ?

Comment: According to spring boot documentation, you can specify multiple profile-specific YAML documents in a single file by using a spring.profiles key to indicate when the document applies.

Comment: Yes agreed... You can specify multiple profile specific information in a single yml. But through spring.profiles.active and not with  spring.profiles https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html.

Comment: @pvpkiran spring.profiles.active is used to turn on certain profiles.  spring.profiles is used in multi-document yaml files to bind documents to specific profiles.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment